# SQL: How to select the oldest date row

Tags: sql, if-statement, select, db2, where-clause

I have a report looks something like this :

| numberOrder | timestamp | id | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2021-06-23-14.00.00.232425 | 11 | done |
| 13 | 2021-06-30-18.00.00.224525 | 22 | done |
| 14 | 2021-07-01-01.00.00.224525 | 23 | done |

This is done with SQL :

```
SELECT numberOrder, timestamp, id, status 
from order 
where status = 'done'
```

I would like the report to show just the oldest row :

| numberOrder | timestamp | id | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2021-06-23-14.00.00.232425 | 11 | done |

```
SELECT numberOrder, timestamp, id, status 
from order 
WHERE timestamp = (select TOP 1 timestamp FROM order by timestamp)
  and status = 'done'`
```

Any ideas ? I try to use min(). Any help is appreciated
And have any ideas if I dont find any status done then find the status cancel ?

I would like the report to show just the cancel row if we dont find any done status :

| numberOrder | timestamp | id | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2021-06-23-14.00.00.232425 | 11 | cancel |

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly unfamiliar with DB2 but I would suggest the following to order the rows by timestamp and fetch the first (oldest) row.

```
select numberOrder, timestamp, id, status 
from order 
where status = 'done'
order by timestamp
fetch first 1 rows only
```

Comment: `with ties` is not applicable to any Db2 platform/version as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yes it appears in DB2 you would need to handle that with a CTE and ranking. I'll remove the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query.
You may run the statement as is if you remove group comments /* */.
The statement without this group comments work on rows with `cancel` statuses only in the base "table" MYTAB. You may comment out the row with 'cancel' and uncomment the row with 'done' inside VALUES to get all rows with statuses `done` only in the base "table". Or construct your base "table" with whatever contents of your original table.
You don't have to edit your query to get both results.
The idea is to enumerate rows row inside both status types. The first rows (ordered by timestamp) in all statues ordered to have the `done` row before the `cancel` one. Finally we get the first row only.

```
WITH 
/*
  MYTAB0 (numberOrder, timestamp, id) AS
(
  VALUES
    (12, '2021-06-23-14.00.00.232425', 11)
  , (13, '2021-06-30-18.00.00.224525', 22)
  , (14, '2021-07-01-01.00.00.224525', 23)
)
, MYTAB AS
(
SELECT *
FROM MYTAB0, 
(
VALUES
'cancel'
--'done'
) S (STATUS)
)
, 
*/
T AS
(
  SELECT T.*, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY STATUS ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) AS RN_
  FROM MYTAB T
  WHERE STATUS IN ('done', 'cancel')
)
SELECT numberOrder, timestamp, id, status
FROM T
WHERE RN_ = 1
ORDER BY DECODE (status, 'done', 0, 1)
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```